# Peter Norvig's spell checker for multi-word matches

Tags: java, algorithm, pattern-matching, spell-checking, match-phrase

Peter Norvig's famous [spellchecker](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html) (Java 8 version [here](https://github.com/unrelatedlabs/SpellingCorrector-Java8/tree/master/src)) is able to correct single words, if something close to that word appears in training data. But how can I adapt it to handle entire phrases. For example, if I have a file where each phrase is separated by a new line :

```
Plastic box
Pencils and sketch
Romeo and Juliet
.
.
.
```

If I tell the algorithm to correct `'Platic'`, it should return `'Plastic box'`. Similarly, if I tell it to correct `'Pencils'`, it should return `'Pencils and sketch'`.

I tried to change the following lines of the above code (Java version) :

```
Stream.of(new String(Files.readAllBytes( dictionaryFile )).toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z ]","").split(" ")).forEach( (word) ->{
            dict.compute( word, (k,v) -> v == null ? 1 : v + 1  );
        });
```

to

```
 Stream.of(new String(Files.readAllBytes( dictionaryFile )).toLowerCase().split("\n")).forEach( (word) ->{
            dict.compute( word, (k,v) -> v == null ? 1 : v + 1  );
        });
```

but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Are you after spell checking or autocompletion ?

Answer (score 0):

If you carefully go through Norvig's `spellchecker`, you will find that as `error model` he uses the words at `edit distance` 1 and 2 from the mis-spelled word. So, if you wanted to correct `Platic` using the file `big.text` as dictionary, it could find the word `Elastic` which is at edit distance 2 as the candidate correct word.

Now, with your modified code, the phrase `Plastic box` is not even within 2 edit distance from the word `Platic` and it will not even be considered as a candidate in the error model, that's why it does not work.

For example, edit distance between them is 5 and then you have to implement functions `edit3`, `edit4` and `edit5` to make it work, which will need to consider millions of words and will be quite inefficient.

Instead, I think you can consider `bigram` `language model` and despite returning a single possible candidate word for a misspelled word, you can return the most likely `bigram phrase`, depending upon the `probability of occurrence` in the dictionary, with the `language model` P(`Plastic box`)=P(`Plastic`)*P(`box`|`Plastic`) and the candidate phrase's probability a P(`Plastic box`)*P(Platic|Plastic Box)`with`Bayes`formula, if you have an`error model` in place (or you have data to learn one).